# vuex : $store.commit vs calling the function directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I figured out that you can pass store mutation functions into HTML events, like :

```
//In the template

<input name="the_field" :value="the_field" @input="updateField"/>

// In the component

methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["updateField"])
}

// In the store

state: {
    the_field: "a value"
},
mutators: {
    updateField (state, e) {
        state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

So just by passing the event as the payload I can have a common field update function for a particular scope, so long as the name is set.

Reading the docs and what people talk about is using `this.$scope.commit("function_name", body)`, even for updating fields from input. In the example I would need to write a component method that makes that call, perhaps picks out the specific data like `this.$scope.commit("updateField", {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value})`. Is it a performance issue to pass around the event object? And more importantly, is it okay to call the mutation function directly vs. using `$store.commit`?

Comment: Any time you think to yourself "is it OK to do this in Vuex?" just turn on Strict Mode to find out: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

Comment: Oh good to know thanks! Didn't break it, interestingly though it didn't break or throw warnings when I called `this.$store._modules.root.state.field_name = "value"`, although it also didn't apply the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it a performance issue to pass around the event object?**

Not really, you have to pass the default event often, since it is not passed to your function or method anymore, if you pass your own payload.

**Is it okay to call the mutation function directly vs. using $store.commit?**

It does not really matter, if you change the state directly with mutations or call actions and use commit. It has more to do with general software design. Mutations change one thing on your state. Actions can call multiple mutations. If you want to change multiple things on the state, you should use an action, which triggers those changes. This way your software becomes more maintainable and easier to debug.

Comment: Hmm I see what you're saying, I'm wondering though about how it would look for an action to trigger multiple mutation functions. The "action" passed in the commit is a String which maps to a mutation function (nicely using the `[CONSTANT] : () => {}` syntax), would you reuse the constant in other stores to trigger additional events? When your store is namespaced, and you call `$store.commit`, does Vuex go through every module to trigger the mutation?

Comment: nvm figured it out ;-) hahah no I see already where the benefit is in using actions and how it makes it way more maintainable, whether I'm passing the event object directly to the action or dispatching it. Thanks!